# How to force SSL renegotiation on apache for a test

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a bug on an application about uploading file on a website wich use x509 client certificate : when a renegotiation occurs during an upload, as the cache is small (128kb), the upload fail.

I need to use the apache SSLRenegBufferSize directive to change the cache size, but I want to test and cannot reproduce the renegotiation to check if everything is ok. How can I force renegotiation from my browser or on apache?

I have found how to do it using openssl : http://blog.ivanristic.com/2009/12/testing-for-ssl-renegotiation.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need to force ssl renegociation from apache side, all you need to do is :

- Set https encryption globally
- Require client certificate only within a specific ‹location› block

**Reference :**

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/419072

"Apache HTTP Server will request SSL renegotiation any time an SSL
session is already established but a request is made for a per-location
context which requires different security -- for example, if you have
the SSLVerifyClient directive in a Directory or Location block. "

Comment: It's already done in production (HTTPS everywhere and clients certs on a Directory directive), but renegotiation still occurs on a random way.

Comment: That should not be random : When client connects there should be global https and renegociation should occur for every get request where Directory requiring client certificate is involved. So at least one renegotiation per hit on protected directory.